# Custom framerate for android camera preview

Tags: android, camera, preview, frame-rate

I am currently planning to develop my first bigger App for Android. However, the whole concept depends on the possibility to set a custom preview framerate for the camera.

As far as my research shows the function `void setPreviewFpsRange (int min, int max)` should allow me to set the framerate to any value. Or are the values returned by `List<int[]> getSupportedPreviewFpsRange ()` the only possible framerates?

At this stage of the project I dont have the possibility to test this with different phones yet.
Does anyone know a good resources, where I can find the framerate ranges of some phones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer:

`void setPreviewFpsRange (int min, int max)`
can only be used with the values given by
`List<int[]> getSupportedPreviewFpsRange ()`

Sadly I couldn't find any resources for the framerate ranges of a variety of phones.

For the ones, that care:

My testphone, the Samsung Galaxy A5 has the ranges:

0: 7000-7000

1: 15000-15000

2: 24000-24000

3: 7000-30000

4: 10000-30000

5: 15000-30000

6: 30000-30000